# How can i get Query columns in SqlAlchemy 1.4 excluding deferred fields?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Recently in SqlAlchemy 1.3 and below i can see query columns using `query.statemennt.columns`. This feature is also included in 1.4, but if i use `defer` in `query.options`, `query.statemennt.columns` returns columns including deferred fields.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, defer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()


class PubTestTable(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'public_table'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(VARCHAR(20))
    name = Column(TEXT)
    create_ts = Column(TIMESTAMP)

def get_query():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://login:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/my_db')
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = session_factory()
    query = session.query(PubTestTable).options(defer('create_ts'))
    return query


if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = get_query()
    print(query.statement.columns)
    print(query)

>> ImmutableColumnCollection(anon_1.id, anon_1.code, anon_1.name, anon_1.create_ts)
>> SELECT public_table.id AS public_table_id, public_table.code AS public_table_code, public_table.name AS public_table_name 
FROM public_table
```

As you can see `create_ts` included to columns, but deferred in compiled statement. How can i get columns like in compiled statement?